# autocmd VimLeave event not firing

Tags: autocmd

I had problem with YCMD server not shutting down properly, so I tried to kill it on VimLeave. After a couple tries I detected that VimLeave/VimLeavePre event not firing on vim exit. VimEnter is working though. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: How did you determine `VimLeave` and `VimLeavePre` are not triggered?

Comment: @SatoKatsura 
`autocmd VimLeave * :!touch ~/hiVimLeave` - nothing and  
`autocmd VimEnter * :!touch ~/hiVimEnter` - file created

Comment: @fourslashw just to be sure you are attempting to trigger these events by issuing a :quit command right?

Comment: @f41lurizer right. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Not a good test, since you no longer have any buffer.  Try something like this instead: `autocmd VimLeave * call writefile([v:dying], '/tmp/some_file', 'a')`.  Don't expect `writefile()` to resolve `~` and the like.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I tried `autocmd VimLeave * call writefile([v:dying], '/home/user/some_file', 'a')` and its not working

Comment: What version of Vim are you running?

Comment: @SatoKatsura `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 31 2015 23:35:24)
Included patches: 1-488, 576
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by jamessan@debian.org`

Comment: You might want to complain to Debian maintainers of Vim then.  It works fine with recent versions of Vim.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Ill try to updating vim then, thanks!

Comment: You might already have a `VimLeave` auto command defined somewhere, which will take precedence; futher ones won't be executed. `:au vimleave` to see what's already defined. Try `au! vimleave` before defining your autocommand to delete any existing ones.